# How to deal with zoom and api call errors

Tags: python, django, jwt, zoom-sdk

When I create jwt and call Zoom api, I get the error `{'code': 124, 'message': 'Invalid access token.'}`. What does this mean?

```
ApiKey = 'xxx'
ApiSercret = 'xxx'
mail = request.POST['mail']
print(mail)
today = datetime.today()
header = {
'alg':'HS256'
}

payload = { 
'iss': ApiKey,
'exp': today + timedelta(hours=1),
}

#https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/specs/rfc7519.html#authlib.jose.rfc7519.JWT.check_sensitive_data
token = jwt.encode(header,payload,ApiSercret,check='true')
print(token)
import http.client

        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.zoom.us")

        headers = {
            'authorization': "Bearer 39ug3j309t8unvmlmslmlkfw853u8",
            'content-type': "application/json"
        }   

        conn.request("GET", "/v2/users?status=active&page_size=30&page_number=1", headers=headers)

        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()

        print(data.decode("utf-8"))
        
params = {
mail:token
}

return render(request,'api/index.html',params)
```

error contents:

```
{'code': 124, 'message': 'Invalid access token.'}
```

Is this error an error on setting Zoom api?
I am trying to get the conference list in Zoom api.
I want to print the contents acquired by get with print.

Answer (score 6):

You create your JWT token, but you don't use it in the API call. You should use your JWT token in the Authorization header

```
'authorization': "Bearer " + token,
```

or add it to your query as a path parameter:

```
&access_token=token
```

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/authorization/jwt/authentication

Comment: do not add it as a query token. inside `authorization` header or `cookies` is recomended